# ObjC make Protocol defined init method as NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols, init

I have a Protocol

```c
// Protocol.h
- (instancetype)initWithConfig:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;
```

A class which `init` is a designated initializer confirms to the protocol

```c
// ClassA.m
- (instancetype)init {
  return [self initWithConfig:nil]; //////////// !!!warning here**
}

- (instancetype)initWithConfig:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    _ivar = @"default value";
    [self setupSomething];
  }
  return self;
}
```

I got a warning: *Designated initializer should only invoke a designated initializer on 'super'*

> 1. I know add `initWithConfig: NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER` to interface or extension can solve this, but it's not I want.
> 2. Write the same logic twice is not my style.
> 3. Add `NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER` to protocol method leads to an error.

Extract a method seems like the only reasonable way? I wonder is there any other way to dismiss the warning?